# Why do these 4 names appear before the cast in the closing credits?

Tags: credits, analyze-this

In Analyze This (1999), do these 4 names appear before the cast in the closing credits?

[image]

Comment: Despite never having seen the movie, im guessing its because they were the four main characters and deserved to be apart from the secondary characters

Comment: Well, probably 'insisted' rather than 'deserved'. ;) It's probably in their contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is referred to as "Main Billing" or "Top Billing".  Paraphrased from the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billing_(filmmaking)#Main_billing):

> The order in which credits are billed generally signify their
>   importance. For example, in films, the first is usually the motion
>   picture company, followed by the producer. Next, depending on his/her
>   standing, the director may be granted an extra, prominent credit.
>
> The major starring actors generally come next, then the title of the
>   movie and the rest of the principal cast.  However, well-known actors may be given top billing for publicity or contractual purposes if juvenile, lesser-known, or first-time performers appear in a larger role
>
> The actors whose names appear first are said to have "top billing".
>   They usually play the principal characters in the film and have the
>   most screen time.  However, well-known actors may be given top billing for publicity or contractual purposes if juvenile, lesser-known, or first-time performers appear in a larger role.